# encoding='utf8' не решает проблему с кодировкой при записи в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv, python-3.6

UPD Если у вас такая же проблема и вы не хотите мучиться, то просто запишите файл в utf-16, а utf-8. У меня в задаче, кроме кириллицы и латиницы были ещё китайские и японские иероглифы, всё нормально записалось.

Я запарсил 200 страниц с данными 10к пользователей одного небольшого сайта и пытаюсь записать их в csv файл в таком формате:

```
Имя, Дата регистрации, Число сообщений

Кирилл, 2012-07-03, 100
Slava, 2013-08-03, 144
თორნიკე, 2015-02-01, 1
```

И так 10 тысяч раз.

Всё идёт хорошо, пока дело не доходит до пользователей со всякими необычными символами в именах, выскакивает ошибка
`'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>`
Я её загуглил и добавил `encoding='utf8'` в свой код, как советовали во всех ответах, ошибка исправилась, но все имена пользователей, в которых использовали кириллицу, записались вот так `РљСЂРµСЃС‚СЊСЏРЅРёРЅ`. Что делать? Может можно как-то разделить имена при парсинге или после него на нормальные и особенные?
Вот функция записи в csv.

```
def save(users, path):
    with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Имя', 'Дата', 'Число сообщений'))
        writer.writerows(
            (users['Nickname'], users['Date'], users['The number of msg']) for users in users
        )
```

Comment: `РљСЂРµСЃС‚СЊСЏРЅРёРЅ` -> `Крестьянин`. Наверное, у вас изначально текст тех страниц был в cp1251 (windows-1251). Попробуйте сначала ваш текст перевести из cp1251 в utf-8, после его сохраняйте в файл. Проверьте кодировку страницы, что скачали парсером

Comment: Кст, смог повторить эту кракозябру: `open('txt.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write('Крестьянин'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251'))`. Т.е. у вас кодировка файла utf-8, а записывается в нем кирилица в кодировке cp1251

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверьте `users['Nickname']`, уверен уже в этих строках у вас будут кракозябры вида `РљСЂРµСЃС‚СЊСЏРЅРёРЅ`.

Если вы откуда-то скачиваете данные с этими строками убедитесь что она пришли как `utf-8` и что вы с ними не делаете преобразования в `cp1251`. Если у вас Windows, то преобразование в `cp1251` может быть неявным при работе с методами `encode`/`decode`, или с `bytes` -- если при работе с ними не указывать кодировку, то подставится системная.

---

Ниже информация по кодировкам (сложная эта тема...).

Файл лучше всего хранить в кодировке `utf-8`, но нужно убедиться, что и остальные строки у вас будут той же кодировке.

Например, берем исходную строку:

```
text = 'Крестьянин'
print(len(text), text)
# 10 Крестьянин
```

Как мы видим, в ней 10 символов. Теперь кодируем ее в байты как `utf-8`:

```
data_utf8 = text.encode('utf-8')
print(len(data_utf8), list(data_utf8))
# 20 [208, 154, 209, 128, 208, 181, 209, 129, 209, 130, 209, 140, 209, 143, 208, 189, 208, 184, 208, 189]
```

И размер стал в два раза больше. Выходит, что кириллица в utf-8 хранится не в одном байте, а в двух. Теперь попробуем эту байтовую строку кодированную в `utf-8` декодировать в строку `cp1251`:

```
new_text = data_utf8.decode('cp1251')
print(len(new_text), new_text)
# 20 РљСЂРµСЃС‚СЊСЏРЅРёРЅ
```

Получаем наши кракозябры. Это потому что cp1251 (она же windows-1251) однобайтовая кодировка.

Берем первые 4 байта из utf-8, декодируем как cp1251 и получаем знакомые символы:

```
print(bytes([208, 154, 209, 128]).decode('cp1251'))
# РљСЂ
```

---

Теперь мы зная причину появления кракозябр можем получить исходную строку через обратные действия:

```
text = 'РљСЂРµСЃС‚СЊСЏРЅРёРЅ'
print(text.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8'))
# Крестьянин
```

Либо повторить:

```
print('Крестьянин'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251'))
# РљСЂРµСЃС‚СЊСЏРЅРёРЅ
```

Comment: На самом деле всё стало хорошо, когда я просто написал encoding='utf-16', а не encoding='utf-8'. Как я прочитал в интернете это тип кодировка которая поддерживает какое-то безумное кол-во символов. Но спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, он тоже помог.

Comment: @Kirill обе кодировки поддерживают абсолютно одинаковое число символов, и простая замена utf-8 на utf-16 не должна была поменять абсолютно ничего (кроме собственно кодировки файла)

Comment: Но почему-то с utf-8, открывая csv файл в Экселе, я вижу кракозябры, а с utf-16 всё нормально. Возможно, это дело в самом  Экселе. В Линуксе, кстати, и с utf-8 всё читается нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Была задача записать dataframe в csv .

Файл скрипта в кодировке utf-8, данные с сервера utf-8, ОС что Windows, что MAC , итог кириллица ломалась.

Задал параметр encoding со значением utf-16 - отработало как ожидалось изначально. Кириллица читаема.

df.to_csv(“”,encoding = “utf-16”, index = False)